# Does firebase work with Firefox OS?

Tags: firefox, firebase, firefox-os, firebase-security

I am trying to figure out if firebase is supported on firefox OS. I guess yes because Firefox OS Apps are built in html5 and javascript but I am not sure if there is a security restriction or something like that.

Comment: Firebase should work correctly on Firefox OS, if you have any trouble getting up and running, please email support@firebase.com.

Comment: is there any examples around github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase should definitely work.

- You will primarily be interacting with it via the REST API
- You will need to ensure that the correct permissions are present in manifest.webapp. Especially the **systemXHR** permission

I have written a tutorial on writing a Firefox OS App that is powered by another mBaaS : Kinvey. Conceptually things are similar and you could take a look : http://rominirani.com/2013/08/19/firefox-os-tutorial-episode-10-using-mbaas/